# Default move constructor taking a const parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, language-lawyer

When defining a class, is the following valid?

```
T(const T&&) = default;
```

I was reading about move constructors [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor) and it explains how the default may still be implicitly declared:

> A class can have multiple move constructors, e.g. both `T::T(const T&&)`
>   and `T::T(T&&)`. If some user-defined move constructors are present, the
>   user may still force the generation of the implicitly declared move
>   constructor with the keyword default.

At the bottom of the page it mentions defect report CWG 2171:

> CWG 2171  C++14
>   `X(const X&&) = default` was non-trivial, made trivial.

Maybe the wiki entry just has a mistake and [CWG 2171](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2171) is only referring to a copy constructor, not a move constructor?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be valid?

Comment: Valid, but rather useless, I would say - how would you move from it?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I [couldn't find a compiler](https://godbolt.org/g/MCdyqw) that will compile it.

Comment: @SergeyA I agree that it is rather useless. A user defined one might still have a purpose. But as to the validity; are you able to compile a class that has `X(const X&&) = default`?

Comment: CWG has been remarkably slow in updating the public version of their issue list. This was moved [as part of P0384R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0384r0.html#2171) in Oulu.

Comment: Anyway, now fixed. The P/R of that issue is a bit misleading since it appeared to touch copy/move equally, but as pointed out below [dcl.fct.def.default]/1.2 prevents anything but `X&&` from being non-user-provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the n4296 draft:

*8.4.2.1 Explicitly-defaulted functions:*

> A function that is explicitly defaulted shall
>
> (1.1) — be a special member function,
>
> (1.2) — **have the same declared function type** (except for possibly
>   differing ref-qualifiers and except that in the case of a copy
>   constructor or copy assignment operator, the parameter type may be
>   “reference to non-const T”, where T is the name of the member
>   function’s class) **as if it had been implicitly declared**, and
>
> (1.3) — not have default arguments.

*12.8.10 Copying and moving class objects:*

> The implicitly-declared move constructor for class X will have the form
>   X::X(X&&)

---

As a consequence the line:

```
T(const T&&) = default;
```

is not valid because the implicitly-declared move constructor has the form of:

```
T(T&&)
```